# facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated

Tags: python, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post an image to my facebook Page through my Python script but this returns me an error 100.

> facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) Parameters do not match any fields
>   that can be updated

**My python code below**:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='my_token')
photo = open("local-filename.jpg", "rb")
graph.put_photo(image=photo, album_path='my_page_id/photos/')
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
i changed my id using the album id taken from url of my facebook page but the error is still the same.

i go to Photos -> open my album -> then from the url

```
https://www.facebook.com/pg/my_page/photos/?tab=album&album_id=105644700884099
```

i take the **105644700884099** value and launch this

```
graph.put_photo(image=photo, album_path='105644700884099/photos/')
```

but still doesn't work

Comment: Your `album_path` is wrong, the API thinks you want to update a field of the page. You need to use `album_id + "/photos"` – https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-photo

Comment: i updated my question adding the correct album_id, the error still occurs